# MissingManifestResourceException is thrown when not found resource key in resource files

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, resourcemanager

I created easy console application for getting resource values. Application is working for existing resource keys. But MissingManifestResourceException is thrown for not existing resourceKeys. What is wrong with my code please? Build action at resource files is set to Embedded Resource.

Program.cs

```
using Framework;

namespace ResourcesConsole
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string resourceValue = CustomResourceManager.GetResourceValue("notExistingResourceKey");
    }
  }
}
```

CustomResourceManager.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace Framework
{
  public class CustomResourceManager
  {
    private static Dictionary<string, ResourceManager> _resourceManagerDict;

    static CustomResourceManager()
    {
      _resourceManagerDict = new Dictionary<string, ResourceManager>();

      string defaultResourceManagerName = "Framework.CustomResources";
      ResourceManager defaultResourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(defaultResourceManagerName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

      _resourceManagerDict.Add(defaultResourceManagerName, defaultResourceManager);
    }

    public static string GetResourceValue(string key, string language = "en")
    {
      CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language);

      string value = null;

      foreach (var resourceManager in _resourceManagerDict)
      {
        value = resourceManager.Value.GetString(key, culture); // MissingManifestResourceException is thrown when resource key is not found in resource file (should return null)

        if (value != null)
          return value;
      }

      return key;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Mysterious question.  What else did you expect to happen when you use a resource that doesn't exist?

Comment: GetString method should return null according to documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bsb0cfet(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's not what the exception is telling you.  The entire chunk of resources can't be found.  You passed the wrong arguments to the ResourceManager constructor.  Double-check the stream name by running ildasm.exe and looking at the .mresource directive in the manifest.

Comment: Arguments to the ResourceManager constructor are correct. I can get resurce value for existing key.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are actually adding more than one resource manager to that dictionary.  And that one of them is bad, thus generating the exception.  Hmm, not so sure it is right about that, it developed a rather nasty crack from that guess.  Sigh, didn't plan to go shopping today.

Comment: My idea was to use more than once ResourceManagers registered to _resourceManagerDict from different assemblies with own resource files. I have only one ResourceManager right now as is visible above - that is complete code. I wouldn't want to use try{}catch, I would like to know what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Problem was that I was missing resource file for invariant (or default) culture. So I  renamed CustomeResources.en.resx to CustomeResources.resx and it works fine